# General covariance and Maxwell equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

In General Relativity, I use the principle of general covariance such that
\begin{equation}
\eta_{\mu\nu}\to g_{\mu\nu}, \quad \partial_\mu\to \nabla_\mu
\end{equation}
so that I re-express physical equations replacing the Lorentz metric with the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ of the manifold and the partial derivative with the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$. When it comes to Maxwell equations, I have some problems regarding the equation
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\delta_{\beta}F_{\gamma\delta}=0 \to \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\nabla_{\beta}F_{\gamma\delta}=0
\end{equation}
Indeed, during my course, it was stated that the quantity $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\nabla_{\beta}F_{\gamma\delta}=0$ ''returns'' as before, with the partial derivative, because ''due to the antisymmetry of the tensor $F_{\gamma\delta}$ and the symmetry of the affine connection, the terms with the Christoffel symbols cancel out''.

I may write
\begin{equation}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\nabla_{\beta}F_{\gamma\delta}=0 \implies \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\delta_\beta F_{\gamma\delta}-\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\Gamma^{k}_{\gamma\beta}F_{k\delta}-\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\Gamma^{k}_{\delta\beta}F_{\gamma k}=0
\end{equation}
The first term with the Christoffel symbols contain the Levi-Civita tensor, which is antisymmetric for the exchange of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, and the affine connection, which is symmetric for the exchange of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ (in a torsionless manifold, which is my case). So this term should be zero. The same can be said for the second term, for the indices $\beta$ and $\delta$. The terms with the Christoffel symbols indeed disappear, leaving me only with the partial derivative term.

My only issue is that in all this I didn't use the antisymmetry of the electromagnetic tensor. Can anyone see the mistake? I KNOW that at some point I have to use this property and I can't understand why I got through the proof without using it, so there must be something wrong in it.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. Perhaps who wrote that statement was thinking about differential forms

Comment: F itself intrinsically contains covariant derivative of the gauge fields A. The equation of F in terms of A become partial derivatives instead of covariant derivatives of A because F is antisymmetric.  Maybe this is where it comes from.

Comment: Probably you’re right Angela!